# Openssl version 1.0.2 is not compatible with docker - django

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a django project that I am moving to docker. I am trying to run the project on my local machine on docker. I have loged into docker on my terminal and i am when i try to run the project, there is an issue with the openssl. can anyone help me figure out a version of openssl that will run on docker. This is what i am currently getting from my terminal..

```
λ docker build -t opentab-test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.093MB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3
 ---> 968120d8cbe8
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f0bba915f632
Step 3/6 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> ee3dcb10168a
Removing intermediate container 9776afaf8e9b
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in b540798048a9
Collecting Django==1.11.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
Collecting olefile==0.44 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading olefile-0.44.zip (74kB)
Collecting openssl==1.0.20 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openssl==1.0.20 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openssl==1.0.20 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

does anyone know a current version of openssl that is compatible with docker or how i can solve this issue.

Comment: The requirement file is wrong. There is no such package "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openssl" for python. There is one https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL. Not sure why you put that in the requirements.txt

Comment: django autmatically generates the requirements file and adds to it as you import it... `Django==1.11.2
olefile==0.44
openssl==1.0.20
Pillow==4.1.1
pip==9.0.1
python==3.6.1
pytz==2017.2
readline==6.2
setuptools==27.2.0
sqlite==3.13.0
tk==8.5.18
wheel==0.29.0
xz==5.2.2
zlib==1.2.8
`
so would it look like pyopenssl=1.0.2 @TarunLalwani

Comment: When I install just django i get only two requirements `Django==1.11.4` and `pytz==2017.2`

Comment: I have imported several different libraries andi think i added them because I didtn add any of them... also I am getting the same issue with `python==3.6.1` i checked to find a current version and nothing came up in docker. @TarunLalwani

Comment: It is not a docker issue. Try a new virtual environment and see if you can install the project there